Type Equality in Pie (The Little Typer)
I was reading "The Little Typer" book, to understand dependent types. I was wondering about the following question.
Suppose you have a proof that T1 and T2 are equal. That is, you can construct a (the (= U T1 T2) Proof) expression. How can you use it?. For example, if you have (the X xexpr) and (the (= U X Y) Proof, can you say (the Y xexpr) in Pie?
I understand that if you prove two non-type expressions of a type equal, then you can use replace to use that fact. I'm not sure how I could do this with types...

A little more context. I was playing around with the Pie language, and I did this:
(claim subtract (-> Nat Nat Nat))
(define subtract  
   (lambda (y x) 
     (rec-Nat x ;Target
              y ;When x is zero
              (lambda (x-1 almost_ans) 
                (which-Nat almost_ans 0 (lambda (almost_ans-1) almost_ans-1))
              )
     )
   )
)

(claim eq (-> Nat Nat Nat))
(define eq (lambda (x y)
             (which-Nat (subtract x y) (which-Nat (subtract y x) 1 (lambda (_) 0)) (lambda (_) 0))
           )
)

;'Proposition generator'. If x and y are equal, return Trivial. Otherwise return Absurd
(claim prop_gen (-> Nat Nat U))
(define prop_gen (lambda (x y) 
                        (which-Nat (eq x y) Absurd (lambda (_) Trivial))
))

(claim final_lemma (Pi ((x Nat))  (prop_gen x x) ))
; How do I prove this? I think that it might be possible for me to prove `(= U Trivial (prop_gen x x))` for all x. I was then thinking how I could use that.

And finally, the reason why I wanted to do the whole thing above was to see if I could prove ¬ (1 = 2), in a slightly different way that was done in chapter 15 of the book. I think that if I could define prop_gen, I could use replace to prove the absurdity.

You can just use replace with the identity function as the motive to transport along an equality of types.
In Martin-Löf type theory, the standard way to prove that e.g. $0 \neq 1$ is to define a type family $T : \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{U}$ such that $T(0) = \top$ and $T(n + 1) = \bot$, then transport $\star : \top$ along the equality $0 = 1$ in $T$ to get an inhabitant of $\bot$. In fact you have to use $\mathcal{U}$: see The Independence of Peano's Fourth Axiom from
Martin-Löf's Type Theory without Universes.
EDIT by Suraaj: The following is a minimal reproducible Pie example:
(claim transport (Pi ((A U) (B U) (eq (= U A B)) (a A)) B))
(define transport 
  (lambda (A B eq a) (replace eq (lambda (x) x) a))
)


Just to be clear - the Peano Axiom in question is "there is no number such that 0 is its sucessor", right?

Yes, that's the one.

Usually one proves equality in order to prove another equality or to prove correct typing of something else. If you showed that $T_1 \equiv T_2$ then you should be able to derive the isomorphism functions   $f:T_1\to T_2$ and $g:T_2\to T_1$. The function $f$ should be able to get you a typechecking judgment $f x : T_2$ if you have $x : T_1$.
It is another question how to write all this in the syntax of Pie. That I am not sure about.
